# How to select specific columns from different tables in mysql database in php

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have 3 tables:

```
request(RequestID,Name,Mobie Number,Vehicle Number,Location)
reqresponse(RequestID,ResponseID,MechanicID,MechanicName)
mechdetails(MechanicID,MechanicName,MechanicMobile,MechanicAvalability)
```

Now, what I want to do is select all data from the `request` table and display it along with details of the `mechdetails` table, where `MechanicAvailability` is set to 'busy'.

**RequestID** is the foreign key in `reqresponse` table.

Can anyone please tell me the MySQL code to do so.

I am working in PHP.

This is where I am right now:

```
SELECT * FROM mechdetails WHERE MechAvailability='Busy' AND 
MechanicID=(SELECT MechanicID FROM reqresponse WHERE ResponseID='$rid')
```

I am really new to MySQL and PHP so please help me!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit the question to show what you've attempted.

Comment: you need to JOIN the tables. (not string the next select statement as you have shown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query

```sql
SELECT * FROM request r
  JOIN reqresponse q ON q.RequestID = r.RequestID
  JOIN mechdetails m ON m.MechanicID = q.MechanicID
  WHERE MechanicAvailability = 'busy'
```

should do the job.

To access the resulting data, use [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php) and [mysqli_result](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.mysqli-result.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can `join` the tables:

```
select r.*, m.*
from request r
inner join reqresponse rr on rr.requestid = r.requestid
inner join mechdetails md on md.mechanicid = rr.mechanicid
where md.mechanicavailability = 'busy'
```